# How to set color of shadow in Gtk2::Frame

Tags: perl, gtk, frame, shadow

I'm trying to make this, I read the manuals, but I dont find anything about this.
I want change the color of a frame border.

Answer (score 1):

tinker you css gtk-theme where GtkFrame is. or code it using GtkCssProvider